# Excel 2013 rounding error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

```
A        B       C
                2.55    
       3.80     2.54    
       3.81     2.49

Average 3.81    2.53

% Difference            33.59580052
```

Trying to get the % diff between avg of column B and the avg of column C. Excel gives the answer above 33.59...  When I do this on my calculator I get 33.68... How do I adjust my formula to get what my calculator shows.

Comment: Just to check on Adam answer: What calculator are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your calculator is giving you the wrong answer, because you are entering rounded values.

`Average(3.8 , 3.81) = 3.805`  (excel displays 3.81, but remembers 3.805)

`Average(2.55, 2.54, 2.49) = 2.5266666....`  (excel displays 2.53)

The percent difference of the two is

`1-(2.5266666.../3.805) = 0.335961454 ~0.336`

To force the (incorrect) answer your calculator is showing you, you need to force excel to round off the values:

```
= 1-round(c4,2)/round(b4,2)
```

Comment: Note:  My values still don't match yours exactly, probably one or more of your original values has hidden significant digits.  Regardless, I am confident the problem is that you are rounding when you type into your calculator.